# Flask loop through images in static directory

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask website set up as such:

```
.flask
   .static
      .images
      .css
   .templates
```

I have my basic.py file as:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/portfolio')
def portfolio():
    return render_template('portfolio.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In the portfolio.html file, I want to be able to collect all of the files in the images directory and display them as a clickable url.

```
<section class="row">
  {% for image in path_to_folder %}
    <section class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="background-color: green;">
      {{ image }}
    </section>
  {% endfor %}
</section>
```

Is there an easy way to get all of the images from the images directory?  Can I store the images into an array and pass them as an argument into the render_template('portfolio.html', images=?")?

Comment: Have you looked at things like `os.listdir` and passing the results of that into the template?

Comment: No, I haven't.  I was seeing answers for tree_paths, but I don't think that is the answer to my solution.  I'm just looking for the best or most efficient way

Comment: Just use `os.listdir` (or `glob.glob` or `pathlib` etc...) to find your images in your static directory and then make sure you render them with a valid href in your template...

Comment: Can you possibly mark up how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `os.listdir` to get all files.

```
@app.route('/portfolio')
def portfolio():
    images = os.listdir(os.path.join(app.static_folder, "images"))
    return render_template('portfolio.html', images=images)
```

And then in your template:

```
<section class="row">
  {% for image in images %}
    <section class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="background-color: green;">
      <a href="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/' + image) }}">{{ image }}</a>
    </section>
  {% endfor %}
</section>
```

Comment: How does one reference the image in the images for loop?  For example if you were creating cards for every image how would you reference the image in src?  {% for image in images %}
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src= ??? class="card-img-top" alt="...">

Comment: It is the same: `src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/' + image) }}"`.

Comment: Thanks @Sraw - I was overthinking it.